# Replace whole word with a symbol using C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace

So I am trying to replace a word like `@theplace` or `@theplaces` using a Regex pattern like:

```
String Pattern = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", PlaceName);
```

But when I do the replacement, it is not finding the pattern, I am guessing it is the `@` symbol that is the problem.

Can someone show me what I need to do to the Regex pattern to get it to work?

Comment: So `PlaceName` contains `@theplace`?

Comment: Why regex in this case and not string.replace?

Comment: @BryanCrosby: Since string replace cannot differentiate between `@a` and `@aplace`? I don't really understand his question, though.

Comment: Can you show a bit more code, and some example of replacements that succeeds and some that fails?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://sscce.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem* is the `\b` (word boundary) before the `@`. There is no word boundary between a space and an `@`.

You could just remove it, or replace it with a non-boundary, which is a capital `B`.

```
string Pattern = string.Format(@"\B{0}\b", PlaceName);
```

<sub>* assuming that `PlaceName` begins with `@`.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The following code will replace any instances of `@thepalace` or `@thepalaces` with `<replacement>`.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(
    "some text with @thepalace or @thepalaces in it."
    + "\r\nHowever, @thepalacefoo and bar@thepalace won't be replaced.", // input
    @"\B@thepalaces?\b", // pattern
    "<replacement>"); // replacement text
```

The `?` makes the preceding character, `s`, optional. I'm using the static [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) method.
The `\b` matches boundaries between word and non-word characters. `\B` matches every boundary that `\b` does not. See [regex boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

**Result**

```
some text with <replacement> or <replacement> in it.
However, @thepalacefoo and bar@thepalace won't be replaced.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string PlaceName="theplace", Replacement ="...";

string Pattern = String.Format(@"@\b{0}\b", PlaceName);
string Result = Regex.Replace(input, Pattern, Replacement);
```